# Manipulate Jenkins Job Parameter before using

Tags: jenkins

I wish to define a Jenkins build parameter, that would typically be entered by a user in a particular way.  In order to be used this parameter must be transformed by a simple function as follows (in shell script)

```
if [ "" != "${SUBPROJ}" ]
then 
    CLEAN=`echo ":${SUBPROJ}:${CLEAN}" | sed 's|/|:|g' `
    END_TARGET=`echo ":${SUBPROJ}:${END_TARGET}" | sed 's|/|:|g' `
fi
```

This will convert something like a/b/c to :a:b:c:

How in Jenkins can I do this conversion before the parameter is used.  Running a shell script step does not change the original parameter.

I looked at the [dynamic parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in) but that doesn't appear to allow for input from the supplied parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables you create and alter in a particular buildstep are scoped just to that build step. If you want to expose a variable you edited to the build steps after your script step you need to take the variable and put the new version back into the environment.  I normally do this by writing the value to a file as a key value pair and using the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

Taking your example the 'CLEAN' variable now holds :a:b:c:  As the next step in your script you need to write that to a file (which I will call newEnvironmentVariables.txt), if you want to replace the SUBPROJ string then you should do something like:

```
if [ "" != "${SUBPROJ}" ]
then 
    CLEAN=`echo ":${SUBPROJ}:${CLEAN}" | sed 's|/|:|g' `
    echo "CLEAN=${CLEAN}" > ${WORKSPACE}\newEnvironmentVariables.txt 
    END_TARGET=`echo ":${SUBPROJ}:${END_TARGET}" | sed 's|/|:|g' `
    echo "END_TARGET=${END_TARGET}" >> ${WORKSPACE}\newEnvironmentVariables.txt 
fi
```

This should produce a text file that contains two lines (I've assumed CLEAN and END_TARGET were empty to begin with).

> CLEAN=:a:b:c:
>   END_TARGET=:a:b:c:

Add an Envinject build step immediately after your script and place the path to the file in the Properties File Path field. If your script was running at the root of your workspace you can use `${WORKSPACE}\newEnvironmentVariables.txt` as your path.

This will create two new variables in your jenkins build job's environment called CLEAN and END_TARGET that you can use in subsequent build steps like any other variable. If you want change the value of SUBPROJ then use that as one of the keys in your key value pairs.

Comment: sounds like envinject would fill the bill.  Thanks.  I will try it when I get a chance.

Comment: This worked, almost.  Due to my configuration of workspaces, simply writing to  newEnvironmentVariables.txt did not put it in my project's workspace.  For that I had to use the $WORKSPACE env var and that was not accessible in a pre-build step.  So I did it as an ordinary build step immediately before the envinject and it then works as intended.  Thanks for the right solution.  And then I wanted > rather than >> to make a new env var file each time.  But close enough to win the prize!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense, our builds always delete the workspace and do a fresh checkout. I guess I didn't think about >> vs >.  Glad it worked.

Comment: hmm.  How do you delete the workspace on each build?  I wanted that but never found the place to do it.

Comment: uh, never mind, that's another plugin,the Workspace Cleanup plugin.  Thanks for alerting me to its existence, even if inadvertently.

Comment: Yep, the workspace cleanup plugin.  There was also an option to wipe out the workspace under the advanced behaviors dropdown of the git scm plugin, but I've had mixed results with that.

Comment: My problem was exporting/injecting script (in my case, windows batch) variables into further build steps. Tried EnvInject as suggested here but without success. Turned to [Environment Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin) and it does the job. Documented in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43784288/1219280).