# How to export windows batch variables as build parameters to following steps in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, is it possible to export windows batch variables as build parameters? I know using build parameters inside windows batch blocks is, I use it a lot.

For example, I have a windows batch block that creates a variable, say A, like

```
SET A="MyVar"
```

Is it possible to use it in running MSBuild, passing it like it was a build parameter, in the (working) syntax of `/p:AssemblyName=%A%` or `/p:AssemblyName=${A}` ?

Neither of these seem to work (my variable is always empty).

---

**Update**: @Tuffwer suggested using the EnvInject plugin. I have been trying, but so far without success. Here's a sample I created to illustrate my original intent:

[image]

I want to create a variable which contents will be determined based on a condition applied in one of the build parameters. Then, I want to use that variable as a parameter to the MsBuild command line, using the /p:[Key]=[Value] syntax (which requires the Jenkins MsBuild plugin, if I am not wrong).

I still can't get this to work, now using EnvInject. I need to reference the value of a windows batch variable inside a further build step.

---

**Update II**: I turned into [Environment Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin), which did the job for me.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42868335/5220640).  tldr: Variables defined in a build step are always scoped locally to that build step. You have to expose them to the rest of the build environment. One way to do this is to use the envinject plugin.

Comment: @Tuffwer: thanks. Please see my update, where I added more details and my attempt so far with EnvInject. I still do not know how to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuffwer suggested using the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin, I tried did not succeed attaining what I intended. I edited my post including my [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) attempt, but in the meantime went searching again for other solutions.

This time I came across the [Environment Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin), which did the job for me.

[image]

Steps:

1. Mark `Generate environment variables from script`
2. For each variable you want to "export", you need to issue an `echo [varName]=[value]` statement.

That's all.
My build then creates an assembly named either *TRUE*.exe or *FALSE*.exe, depending on the build parameter `MyBool` value.